# asm function code syntax error (comma, colon, etc.)?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86-16

I'm new to assembly language and my professor wanted us to test out code where we use a game and try using the save and restore functions to save video memory. However, when I plugged in the code for a game I've made, I receive syntax errors

game.asm:31: error: comma expected after operand 1
game.asm:174: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
game.asm:182: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand

this was the code that gave the syntax errors

```
saved_screen:   db 4000 dup(?);

restore_video:
 mov si, offset saved_screen;
 sub di,di
 mov cx, 2000
 rep movsw
 ret

save_video:
 mov di, offset saved_screen;
 sub si,si
 mov cx, 2000
 push ds
 push es
 pop ds
 pop es
 rep movsw
 push ds
 push es
 pop ds
 pop es
 ret
```

specifically the error was at..

```
saved_screen:   db 4000 dup(?);

mov si, offset saved_screen;

mov di, offset saved_screen;
```

I am not currently able to reach my professor right now so I would like your help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which assembler do you use? Make sure it matches the syntax of the code. In any case, I'd remove the semicolons `;` or put a space before them.

Comment: Those lines are using MASM syntax.  Building that with NASM would give errors on those lines.  The code style otherwise is NASM-like, using labels instead of PROC.  In NASM, `mov reg, symbol` puts the address into the register, like MASM `offset`.  And read the NASM manual about `resb` or `times 4000 db 0`

Comment: @Peter Cordes yeah i think i used masm syntax. Thank you!!

Comment: @Peter Cordes I'm looking it up right now but I realized it might not be the right size, I'm using 64-bit linux and nasm so do you have a good idea how i should change the program to fit the 6-bit mode

Comment: Sure, delete it and restart from scratch.  Nothing this code does is useful in 64-bit user-space.  You don't have direct access to the VGA video RAM, and you don't need to mess around with segment registers to copy memory.  You have a simple flat address space.

Comment: You might want to use dosbox.